# Three.js TransformControl attach -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: three.js

I added the code from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/controls/TransformControls.js

to my angular project and create the transformcontrols:

```
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    const material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ transparent: false, opacity: 0.9, color: 0x00ff00 });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.control = new TransformControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.control.addEventListener('change', this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera));
    this.control.addEventListener('dragging-changed', function (event) {
      console.log("dragging-changed", event);
      this.controls.enabled = !event.value;
    });
    this.scene.add(this.control);
    this.scene.add(mesh);
    this.control.reset();
    this.control.attach(mesh);
```

But when attaching I get the error:

```
'Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')\nTypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')\n    at TransformControls.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:245488:18)\n    at TransformControls.set (http://localhost:4200/main.js:86:31)\n    at TransformControls.attach (http://localhost:4200/main.js:555:21)\n    at EditorComponent.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4200/main.js:8436:26)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:297508:71\n    at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:5737:21)\n    at __awaiter (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:297504:12)\n    at EditorComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:4200/main.js:8421:65)\n    at callHook (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:348386:14)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.control.addEventListener('change', this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera));
```

was the problem. After I removed it it worked